# Element won't anchor to screen bottom when I change bottom property dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, anchor

I'm trying to write a javascript script that dynamically anchors elements to the bottom of the page when necessary. Here's a sample my code:

```
thebox.style.right = (window.innerWidth - topleft.Left - abs.Left - thebox.offsetWidth)+'px'
thebox.style.left = ''
thebox.style.top = (topleft.Top - abs.Top)+'px'
thebox.style.bottom = ''
```

This code is called when I want to anchor the element to the top and right of the page. Other code is called for other anchor positions.

The problem is, it will only anchor to the right of the page if the element was originally anchored to the right of the page to begin with. When I dynamically anchor something to the left that was originally anchored to the right, it correctly anchors to the left. And when I anchor it back to the right, it correctly anchors to the right. But if it was never anchored to the right, it never anchors to the right no matter what I do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a little more context would help...perhaps do a quick example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Im not sure that this is the solution but it might be worth a try.

```
//anchoring left 
thebox.style.left= '0';
thebox.style.right= 'auto';

//anchoring right
thebox.style.left= 'auto';
thebox.style.right= '0';
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't need JavaScript to position the elements. If you add your elements at `body` level and absolute position them, you can achieve it with just CSS. Then to change the position of any element just assign the appropriate class in JS dynamically.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/x8CTY/